# Jquery 'Bad Request' error while passing array in url

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

I have array with more than 10 records in it and i want to pass it to the controller but it pop ups the error saying bad request.

Following is my code:

```
$('#submit_fourth').click(function(){
        //send information to server
             $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php print site_url('orgnization/storeData'); ?>/'+fields


        });

    });
```

As shown in the code, `fields` is the array containing data. Now following is the error message in the firebug.

[image]

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$('#submit_fourth').click(function(){
        //send information to server
             $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {fields:fields},
            url: '<?php print site_url('orgnization/storeData'); ?>/'
           success: function(data)
            {
                  console.log('Success');
            }

            });

        });
```

and in php code:

```
    public function storeData()
    { 
      ....
      if($this->input->post())
      {
                $fields = $this->input->post('fields'); 
      }
      ....
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending data array in wrong format.See example below

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "<?php print site_url('orgnization/storeData'); ?>",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }//your data will send in this format
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON.stringify() before you post data; and give it in data, dont append in url.

```
$('#submit_fourth').click(function(){
    //send information to server
         $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php print site_url('orgnization/storeData'); ?>/',
        data: JSON.stringify(fields)


    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you want to send GET request:

```
$data = array('foo'=>'bar',
              'baz'=>'boom',
              'cow'=>'milk',
              'php'=>'hypertext processor');


echo site_url('orgnization/storeData') . '?' . http_build_query($data);
```

and
`type: 'POST'` change to `type: 'GET'`

If you want send POST:

```
$.post("<?php print site_url('orgnization/storeData'); ?>", <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>)
   .done(function( data ) {
      alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```